# how to change element to Id for show timer

Tags: javascript, timer

This code

```js
function toTimeString(seconds) {
    return (new Date(seconds * 1000)).toUTCString().match(/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/)[0];
}

function startTimer() {
    var dataStartElem = $(this);
    var dataStart = dataStartElem.attr('data-start');
    if (dataStart == 'false') {
        dataStartElem.attr('data-start', 'true');
        var nextElem = dataStartElem.parents('#count').next();
        var duration = dataStartElem.attr('data-value');
        var a = duration.split(':');
        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
        setInterval(function () {
            seconds--;
            if (seconds >= 0) {
                nextElem.html(toTimeString(seconds));
                dataStartElem.attr('data-start', 'false');
            }
            if (seconds === 0) {
                alert('sorry, out of time');
                clearInterval(seconds);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
$('#timer').on('click', startTimer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="timer" class="btn btn-primary" href="https://google.com" target="blank" data-value='00:00:05' data-start='false' role="button">Link 5 seconds <i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td id="count">00:00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <a id="timer" class="btn btn-primary" href="https://google.com" target="blank" data-value='00:05:00' data-start='false' role="button">Google 5 minutes <i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td id="count">00:00:00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The code above does not work when I use

```
    <td id="count"> 00:00:00 </td>
```

but works when only using https://jsfiddle.net/qxxoqmqd/3/

```
    <td> 00:00:00 </td>
```

How to work when using

```
    <td id="count"> 00:00:00 </td>
```

I've replaced the dataStartElem into dataStartId but that also does not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @Kaddath thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's (`#timer` or `id="timer"`) are unique to a webpage. `$('#timer')` will only match exactly one element. Try changing timer to a class, and using the class selector in jQuery `$('.timer')`:

It also appears that #count is not a parent of the timer you're trying to find. You cannot just simply do `dataStartElement.parents('#count')`. If you modify your DOM, you need to update this line to reflect how to find the count html to update. See [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp) for more helpful information on traversing the DOM.

Using `dataStartElem.parent().next('.count')` I was able to find your count element in order to update the html.

```js
function toTimeString(seconds) {
    return (new Date(seconds * 1000)).toUTCString().match(/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/)[0];
}

function startTimer() {
    var dataStartElem = $(this);
    var dataStart = dataStartElem.attr('data-start');
    if (dataStart == 'false') {
        dataStartElem.attr('data-start', 'true');
        var nextElem = dataStartElem.parent().next('.count');
        var duration = dataStartElem.attr('data-value');
        var a = duration.split(':');
        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
        setInterval(function () {
            seconds--;
            if (seconds >= 0) {
                nextElem.html(toTimeString(seconds));
                dataStartElem.attr('data-start', 'false');
            }
            if (seconds === 0) {
                alert('sorry, out of time');
                clearInterval(seconds);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
$('.timer').on('click', startTimer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary timer" href="https://google.com" target="blank" data-value='00:00:05' data-start='false' role="button">Link 5 seconds <i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td class="count">00:00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <a class="btn btn-primary timer" href="https://google.com" target="blank" data-value='00:05:00' data-start='false' role="button">Google 5 minutes <i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td class="count">00:00:00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```